# 500 Internal Server Error Issue

Tags: cpanel, internal-server-error

My website is [this](http://wordpressfixer.us/). I've deleted all files from **public html** folder. Only **cgi-bin** lies in it. And now i'm facing **500 Internal Server Error**.
I don't know how to handle this. Anyone like to help me out ????

Comment: Check your server's logs for the details of the error. Try adding an `index.html` for starters.

Comment: `home/wordpressfixer/public_html/.htaccess: </FilesMatch> without matching <FilesMatch> section`
how to solve this @ceejayoz

Comment: You've messed up your `.htaccess` file. Open it up and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete .htaccess file since you have no folders there so I see no point in keeping an .htaccess files with rules. At the time of my answer I can see a wordpress site loading just fine using the URL that you have provided. I assume the problem is gone?!